# How can I pass data to broadcastAs event method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass data to the method [broadcastAs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#broadcast-name), but I keep getting the error `Too few arguments to function App\Events\NotifyUser::broadcastAs()`. Below is what I have tried.

I'm calling the event on the Controller this way:

```
event(new NotifyUser('8', 'banned'));
```

And I'm trying to access the data on the event this way:

```
public $user;

public $msg;

public function __construct($user, $msg)
{
    $this->user = $user; //8
    $this->msg = $msg; //banned
}

public function broadcastAs($user)
{
    return "user-logged-$user";
}
```

It works just fine without the *$user* variable in the *broadcastAs*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it with your set property (`$this->user`) rather than an argument.

```
public $user;

public $msg;

public function __construct($user, $msg)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->msg = $msg;
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return "user-logged-" . $this->user->id;
}
```

However, are you sure you want to use this there?

```
 window.Echo.private('channel-name.' + user_id)
        .listen('BroadcastClassName', (e) => { }  
        // you'll edit listen() with broadcastAs
```

---

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('user.'.$this->user->id);
}

// broadcastAs() is optional
public function broadcastAs() {
    return 'customEventName';
}
```

`broadcastAs()` is optional for overriding event's name, as default one is class's name itself.

With my last chunk, this is what you'll get.

```
 window.Echo.private('user.' + user_id)
        .listen('customEventName', (e) => { }
```

If you don't have `broadcastAs()` at all, in your case, your event name will be `"NotifyUser"`, which seems right to me.

```
    window.Echo.private('user.' + user_id)
        .listen('NotifyUser', (e) => { }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was doing it totally wrong. You made me realize, and I made it right with the suggestion you gave.